# References is not Cascading

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Consider the following code:

```
class PrivilegeMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Privilege>
{
    public void Override(FluentNHibernate.Automapping.AutoMapping<Privilege> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Table("Privileges");

        mapping.References<Role>(x => x.Role)
            .Cascade.All();

        mapping.Map(x => x.Access);
    }
}
```

In my code, I then create a user which has several privileges.  When trying to save the user, this crashes the program with the error: "object references an unsaved transient instance"  It claims that the role object is not save.  How do I get it to cascade?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the mapping for the User class. do you have Cascade.All(); on the Roles propery ? is it a reference , a HasMany or a HasManyToMany?

Answer (score 0):

I just said the heck with it and changed over to static mappings rather than overriding everything I don't like.  It works the way I want to now.